# Calling Components in NgFor - Angular

Tags: angular, components, ngfor

I'm trying to call dynamic components in ngFor, but i cannot use variables inside Tags HTML.

What i have:

```
components = [component1, component2, component3];

<div *ngFor="let component of components">
  <component></component>
</div>
```

Result i want:

```
<component1></component1>
<component2></component2>
<component3></component3>
```

Result i get:

```
<component></component>
<component></component>
<component></component>
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do it that way.  You'll have to use the component loader:

https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader